# Example of normal linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, isometry

Let $V$ be a real inner product space and $g:V\rightarrow V$ a normal linear map.
Can you give me an example of:
1- A map $g$ that is not self-adjoint?
2- A map $g$ that is not an isometry?
3- A map $g$ that is not orthodiagonalizable?

Comment: What have you got?

Comment: @AndreasT:  It seems likely that the OP imposes a requirement that $g$ is normal (for each part of the exercise).

Comment: @hardmath That is right, I hadn't noticed that his examples weren't

Comment: The example of a nonisometry was *normal* (being symmetric).

Comment: @hardmath The examples are gone now

Comment: @hardmath yes, sorry, I noticed the *normal* requirement only after I posted the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} \in M_2(\mathbb{R}). $$

We have

$$ AA^T = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 + b^2 & 0 \\ 0 & a^2 + b^2 \end{pmatrix}, \\
A^TA = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 + b^2 & 0 \\ 0 & a^2 + b^2 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

so $A^TA = AA^T$ and $A$ is a normal matrix. If $b \neq 0$, then $A$ is not self-adjoint and not orthogonally diagonalizable (as this is equivalent). If $a^2 + b^2 \neq 1$, then $A$ is not orthogonal.

Thus, if $b \neq 0$ and $a^2 + b^2 \neq 1$, the corresponding map $T_A \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T_A(x) = Ax$ (considering $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard inner product) is not self-adjoint, not an isometry and not orthogonally diagonalizable. In fact, it is not diagonalizable (as the roots of the characteristic polynomial $a \pm ib$ are complex).

Comment: If we're considering complex vector spaces, then orthodiagonalitibility and being self-adjoint is not equivalent anymore, is it? Over $\mathbb C$, $A$ _is_ (ortho)diagonalizible, isn't it?

Comment: Yep. Over $\mathbb{R}$ an operator $T$ is orthogonally diagonalizable if and only if $T$ is self-adjoint. Over $\mathbb{C}$, an operator $T$ is orthogonally diagonalizable if and only if $T$ is normal. Thus, considering $A$ as a complex matrix, it is normal and thus orthogonally diagonalizable (with complex orthogonal eigenvectors).